# How to get Google+ contacts after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-plus

I am developing ionic application with backendless and angularjs. I integrated google+ with firebase. Once we click on google+ button it will give popup for credentials. After successful login firebse will check whether the user authenticated or not.After authentication I am making api call to get google+ contacts.I got 403 status code.

I have tried in many ways,none of them are not working.
could anybody tell the steps to get google+ contacts after login

This is my code:

```
var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXX';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login';


gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}

function checkAuth() {
  var r = gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: scopes,
    immediate: true
  });
  gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
      'userId': 'me',
      'collection': 'visible'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log('Num people visible:' + resp.totalItems);
    });
  });
}
```